# how can I get this number commas format function to work with a 4-precision decimal?

Tags: javascript, replace, precision

I'm currently using the following function which formats a number with commas:

```
numberWithCommas(x) { return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","); }
```

For example, the function above formats 20000 as 20,000. However, the function above doesn't seem to work with numbers with 4-precision decimals. For example, 20000.0000 returns as 20,000.0,000. How can I update the numberWithCommas function above so that it inserts commas properly for my second scenario above?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Answer (score 1):

Changing your regex to `/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d).)/g` seems to fix your problem.

Comment: Note: This will add commas _only if_ there are decimals.

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work as expected:

```
numberWithCommas = (x) => { const splitUp =  x.toString().split('.') ;return [splitUp.shift().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","), ...splitUp].join('.'); }
```

Answer (score 0):

That should fix it. Your regex is not taking into account decimals. Also `toString()` is removing your decimals:

```js
const regex = /(?=(?=\d*\.)(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g;
const str = `10000000.0000`;
const subst = `,`;

const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape a period with a quantifier (`\.+`) at the end, but inside the brackets so the RegExp looks like: `/\B(?=(?!\.)(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.+)/g`

```js
document.write(200000.12345.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?!\.)(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.+)/g, ","));
```